# getting a subString Out from a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

```
1 US Dollar = 3.673 United Arab Emirates Dirham
```

How to get only value `3.673` from this string?

I tried the following code, but didn't work.

```
NSString *a = [[xmlParser array]objectAtIndex:2];
NSRange startRange = [a rangeOfString:@"="];
NSLog(@"%u",startRange.location+1);
NSRange endRange = [a rangeOfString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%u",endRange.location);
NSString *subString = [a substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startRange.location + 1, endRange.location)];
NSLog(@"%@",subString);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
 NSArray *aArray = [a componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; //your string here
 NSString *dollarValue = [aArray objectAtIndex:4]; //get dollar value from array
 NSLog(@"%@",dollarValue);
```

Comment: Yes, this is better than mine if you know that the value you want is always the 5th (index 4) word in the sentence.

Comment: it worked fine for me earlier but suddenly i app is crashing i am getting the error in the first line and the log says.*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CurrencyValues componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5913d00'

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like...

```
NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (NSString *word in words) {
    //check for equals sign and then take the next one.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 US Dollar = 3.673 United Arab Emirates Dirham"];  
components = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
str = [components objectAtIndex:4];
NSLog(@"Str:%@", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *param = nil;
    NSRange start = [a rangeOfString:@"="];
    if (start.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        param = [a substringFromIndex:start.location + start.length];
        NSRange end = [param rangeOfString:@"United"];
        if (end.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            param = [param substringToIndex:end.location];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"param: %@",param);
```